# php PDO error "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry"

Tags: php, pdo

I want to make an simple register form where I want to check if the email is already used and if not insert the data in my db. if I submit the form I get this fatal error "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry" but the data is submitted anyway, and I can see it in my db. If i only insert the data or check if the email is already used i don't get this error.maybe someone can help me with this.
this is the code:

html

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" autofocus="on">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

php

```
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO($attr, $user, $pass, $opts);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    throw new PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

if($_POST)
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $emailAbfrage = "SELECT email FROM accounts";
    $result = $pdo->query($emailAbfrage);
    while($row = $result->fetch())
    {
        if($email == $row['email'])
        {
            echo "email ist schon vergeben";
        }
        else 
        {
            $insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `accounts`(`kundenname`, `email`) VALUES (?,?)");
            $insert->execute(array($name, $email));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with the code snippet:

1. You loop over all the accounts.  If you get a match then you print `email is schon vergeben` but you don't `break` so it will still loop over all the other accounts, where you will get to the `else`, try to insert the account again, and get the `Duplicate Entry` exception.
2. Your query literally returns *all* the accounts in the database.  A better one would be `SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email=?` which would just return the one account you care about.
3. Even better than doing a `SELECT`, you can do `INSERT INTO accounts(kundenname, email) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email=VALUES(email)`.  This does an insert only if the account doesn't exist.  You can check the returned row count to see if it added a new record or not.  Change the part after `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` to suite your needs in the case that the account is already there.

Comment: Thanks for your help Oz Solomon it helped me i just did not thought about that it would try to insert it multiple times. now i've done it like "SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email=?" this. Again thanks!